# Make the values of a function zero, when it becomes complex or indeterminate

Tags: functions, conditional

I have a function like this:

```
ftr[x_, v_] := (
  0.9003163161571062` (1 + E^(-(x^2/8)) - v^2))/(1 - 
    2 (-E^(-(x^2/8)) + v^2))^(3/2) + (
  Sqrt[E^(-(x^2/8)) - v^2] (1 - 2 Log[-4 (-E^(-(x^2/8)) + v^2)]))/(
  2 \[Pi])
```

For some values of x,v, the function gives complex values or indeterminate. I want to change this to zero. That is, whenever the function becomes complex or give indeterminate, I want to change the value to zero.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does this work?

```
ftr[x_, v_] := 
 With[{z = (0.9003163161571062` (1 + E^(-(x^2/8)) - v^2))/(1 - 
         2 (-E^(-(x^2/8)) + v^2))^(3/2) + (Sqrt[
         E^(-(x^2/8)) - v^2] (1 - 
          2 Log[-4 (-E^(-(x^2/8)) + v^2)]))/(2 \[Pi])
   },
  If[z \[Element] Reals, z, 0.]
  ]
```

Comment: Thank You Sir. This works

Comment: Fine! You're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

```
FunctionDomain[(0.9003163161571062` (1 + E^(-(x^2/8)) - v^2))/(1 - 
        2 (-E^(-(x^2/8)) + v^2))^(3/2) + (Sqrt[
        E^(-(x^2/8)) - v^2] (1 - 
         2 Log[-4 (-E^(-(x^2/8)) + v^2)]))/(2 π), #] & /@ {x, v}

(* {E^(-(x^2/8)) - v^2 > 0, E^(-(x^2/8)) - v^2 > 0} *)
```

**EDIT:** Added [`NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html) test so that symbolic input does not evaluate to zero.

```
Clear[ftr]

ftr[x_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] := (0.9003163161571062` (1 + E^(-(x^2/8)) - v^2))/
       (1 - 2 (-E^(-(x^2/8)) + v^2))^(3/2) + (Sqrt[E^(-(x^2/8)) - v^2] 
        (1 - 2 Log[-4 (-E^(-(x^2/8)) + v^2)]))/(2 π) /; 
  Exp[-x^2/8] - v^2 > 0

ftr[x_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] := 0
```

Checking,

```
ftr @@@ {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {x, v}}

(* {0.140982, 0, ftr[x, v]} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

one approach is to make up a utility function..

```
onlyreal[v_Real] = v;
onlyreal[v_Complex /; Head@Chop@v == Real] := Chop[v] (*optional*)
onlyreal[v_] = 0;
ftr[x_, v_] := 
 Module[{r}, (0.9003163161571062` (1 + E^(-(x^2/8)) - v^2))/(1 - 
       2 (-E^(-(x^2/8)) + v^2))^(3/2) + (Sqrt[
       E^(-(x^2/8)) - v^2] (1 - 
        2 Log[-4 (-E^(-(x^2/8)) + v^2)]))/(2 \[Pi])]
t = Quiet@*onlyreal@*ftr[0, 100]
```

> 0

```
Quiet@*onlyreal@*
   ftr @@@ {{0, 0}, {1, 100}, {Infinity, Infinity}, {a, b}}
```

> {0.0644157, 0, 0, 0}

note you have not said what to do with non numeric results.

Comment: Sir, When you evaluate the function we get real values in some regions in the x-v space and indeterminate in some regions and complex in rest of the regions in x-v space. I want to asign all values to zero that are not real

Comment: thats what this does